# Only first card return from StreamBuilder in Flutter run --release

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am creating flutter web app with Firebase realtime database. I just got different result for the release mode, there are only one Card widget return in release mode.

I am using "List items" as container and put the cards into that. Is't looks great in debug mode, but why only one card in the gridView after turned into release mode.

debug mode command: flutter run
release mode command: flutter run --release

[Different between release mode and debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02s1J.jpg)

Put my Scaffold class as following.

```js
Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Sense'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(133, 1, 132, 1),
          ),
          body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: databaseRef.onValue,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
              if (!snap.hasError && snap.hasData) {
                fb.DataSnapshot snapshot = snap.data.snapshot;
                List<Widget> items = [];
                snapshot.forEach((e) => items.add(Card(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      elevation: 5,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //     border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              child: Text(
                                e.key.toUpperCase(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    letterSpacing: 3,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  //     border: Border.all(color: Colors.green)),
                                  child: FittedBox(
                                      child: Text(
                                    e.val().toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 1, 132, 1)),
                                  )))),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            height: 50,
                            // decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            //     border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
                            child: FittedBox(
                              child: Text(
                                'Unit: ',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )));
                return GridView.extent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 480,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    children: items);
              } else {
                return SpinKitDoubleBounce(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(133, 1, 132, 1));
              }
            },
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            child: SvgPicture.asset('logo.svg'),
          )),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your StreamBuilder need to specify the Object. And if it's a List just check List.isNotEmpty

```
StreamBuilder<List<Object>>(
        stream: databaseRef.onValue,// need to return : Stream<List<Object>>
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (!snap.hasError && snap.hasData) {
            final items = snap.data;
            if(items.isNotEmpty){
              ...
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It can fix by the following method.

```
snapshot.forEach((e) => items.add(Card(...)))
```

to

```
snapshot.forEach((e) {items.add(Card(...))})
```

Does anyone know the root cause?